# Creating a searchable database in WordPress

Tags: database, wordpress

I am now trying to create a WordPress website, where logged in users can submit details about a Person or Company using a form and other users can retrieve this information using a search form.

Example : User 1 adds a company
Name : Google
Headquarters : United Stater

User 2 adds another company
Name : Microsoft
Headquarters : United States.

And then user 3 searchs Headquarters field : US 
and get both the companies in the result.

Is there any plugin I can achieve this function in WordPress?
Tried browsing through the site, but couldn't yet find one.

Comment: You should start reading here. https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Comment: This is not a programming question, you are asking about a plugin to do a task without programming. This is not the right place for this question